# Why don’t I see tag "h1" after starting the WSGI script?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I start `UWSGI` script command -

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi
```

in folder myapp.

There is a file (script) `wsgi.py` with content:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ["<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"]
```

After I open my IP 0.0.0.0:5000. No error but not see tag (title) `h1`.

In the browser a blank page and terminal:

```
[pid: 30736|app: 0|req: 11/11] 176.57.76.232 () {34 vars in 672 bytes} [Sun Apr  7 12:12:22 2019] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 30736|app: 0|req: 12/12] 176.57.76.232 () {36 vars in 645 bytes} [Sun Apr  7 12:12:22 2019] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: What does uWSGI output?

Comment: @AKX I'm add information in the ask